# FCKeditor, removing stuff

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

I am using FCKEditor in a CMS and need to post some javascript code in the editor.
This is stored in my database but it removes the + sign from this javascript code:

```
function _check(val){ 
  loadFragmentInToElement('captcha_check.php?val='+val,'captcha_div','');
}
```

Now why would it remove the + sign?

I've tried using &#43; and %2B but then it posts &#43; and %2B instead of a + sign.
No, outside parties will not be able to access this to post stuff.

Edit....

The form with the editor is submitted using a javascript function 
called submitform. The editor content is passed as an object called 
noofeditor. I see where it 'escapes' the code retrieved from 
the editor using this:

```
if(noofeditor){
 var editorArray=noofeditor.split('::'); 
 for (l=0;l<editorArray.length;l++){
   strData += "&"+editorArray[l]+"="+escape(FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance(editorArray[l]).GetXHTML());
 }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent it from escaping the + sign?

Comment: Why would it remove the + sign where exactly? What do you put in, and what comes out?

Comment: Can you not see it in the code posted above? It is put in the source in the editor. I open the editor, click Source and paste the HTML, including javascript, in the editor, then click submit to store to the database.

Comment: Checks for the value of the editor's content shows that it removes the + sign.

Comment: If I leave it like the code above, it comes out like this:     `loadFragmentInToElement('captcha_check.php?val=' val, 'captcha_div','');`                                                    Note the space where the + sign was.

Comment: Could it be that since it is being sent in a POST that that is what is really taking it out and replacing it with a space?

Comment: Freaking comment box won't let me post formatted code. see the edit in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following:

```
function _check(val){ 
  var path = 'captcha_check.php?val='+val;
  loadFragmentInToElement(path,'captcha_div','');
}
```

Comment: It will also remove it in that code. See the text after the words Edit... in the original post.

Comment: I do not understand - the plus sign goes away when we define path. We don't need it, just a string like 'captcha_check.php?val=foobar'. We want foobar, not +foobar

Comment: Can't see the forest for the trees, huh? The + sign is there because the code is supposed to CONCATENATE the string 'captcha_check.php?val=' and the value of the parameter called val.

Comment: and CONCATENATE it did! check this out: var path = 'captcha_check.php?val='+val;. Assuming val=foobar, the result of that line of code is 'captcha_check.php?val=foobar'. No plus signs, no funny behaviour. Just a whole lot of misunderstanding.